# What's a phrase to describe this situation?

Tags: terminology, logic

Let's say hypothetically a country proactively allocate millions of tax dollars towards creating vaccines and setting up camps to quarantine and prevent the spread of Ebola in a neighbouring country. Two months later the Ebola is completely gone. Then people from the country that spent millions are mad and say "look at all this money spent, this country didn't even want our help and it was purged of Ebola really quickly, what was the point, we are in a worst situation than before because the country hates us now and we are out millions on vaccines which weren't used", etc. But those people are making the assumption that things WOULDN'T HAVE BEEN MUCH WORSE had they not done anything. There COULD have been unforetold catastrophic events as a result of inaction. This is a usual argument I see against proactive government foreign policy. Is there a name for this fallacy because I see it all the time. Thanks.

Comment: It wouldn't be considered a "logical fallacy", as there are assumptions involved with no reliable exterior data to extrapolate from.

Comment: Okay, is there any name in the english language used identifying this assumption?

Comment: In fact, it could be argued that **your** logic contains a fallacy. In its simplest form, the argument is that *correlation does not imply causation*. I could also have an ebola-repellent rock that I keep in my pocket. If I don't get ebola, does that mean the rock worked?

Comment: I don't understand how you gather that from my post. To reiterate, people would use the bad situation that resulted from action against a bad situation as evidence that action should not have been taken. But, as is the very purpose of proactivity, if you have a scenario where there is potential for catastrophe, you take exaggerated precaution in relation to the threat at hand...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a *damned if you do, damned if you don't* fallacy.  If the proactive effort works, opponents will claim it was not needed and the money was wasted.  If the effort fails, the same opponents will claim not enough money was spent!

Another term for this thinking is *politics as usual.*